# Use of definition of limit to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{h→0} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}- \sqrt[3] {2}} {h}= \dfrac {1}{ 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{4} }$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I know that by definition I have to prove that $$\displaystyle\lim_{h→0} \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}- \sqrt[3] {2}} {h}= \dfrac {1}{ 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{4}  }⟺∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0,\, 0<|h−0|<δ⟹| \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}- \sqrt[3] {2}} {h}- \dfrac {1}{ 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}  } |<ϵ.$$

I have this:

$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}- \sqrt[3] {2}} {h}- \dfrac {1}{ 3\cdot  \sqrt[3]{4}} \cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{2}} $

= $\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}- \sqrt[3] {2}} {h}- \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{6} $

=$ \dfrac{6\cdot \sqrt[3]{2+h}-6\cdot \sqrt [3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot h}{6h} $

=$ \left |\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{2+h})^2 + \sqrt[3]{2+h}\sqrt[3]{2}+(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 } -  \dfrac {\sqrt[3]{2}} {6}\right | $

=$   $

I don't know how continue for use the fact $|h|<\delta$

The original exercise says: $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$. Found $\displaystyle\lim_{h→0} \dfrac {f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried multiplying top and bottom of $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2+h}-\sqrt[3]{2}}{h}$ by $(2+h)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2+h}+2^{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: +1 : very elegant.  Probably worth mentioning where the *rabbit out of the hat* came from: re the factor to be applied is $$\frac{\left[(2 + h)^{(1/3)}\right]^3 ~-~ \left[(2)^{(1/3)}\right]^3}{(2 + h)^{(1/3)} ~-~ (2)^{(1/3)}}.$$

Comment: Yes lemon. I did. I have 1 over your suggestion.

Comment: @user2661923 Can you explain me what you are suggesting? Please.

Comment: @ LuisaFernandaRojas my username is no lemon no melon, it's a palindrome, read it backwards :)

Comment: did you get $\Bigg|\frac{1}{(2+h)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot \sqrt[3]{2+h}+2^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{1}{3\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}\Bigg|$?

Comment: Oh, I can see it. Nice. And yes, I have that. I was trying to solve the subtraction but it didn't come up with something conclusive. I do not know what else to do

Comment: @LuisaFernandaRojas "Can you explain me what you are suggesting?"  There are actually two points.  The first is, if you followed the instructions of "no lemon no melon" carefully, **did that solve the problem**?  The second is that in general, $$\frac{x^3 - y^3}{x - y} = (x^2 + xy + y^2).$$ Notice that in my fractional expression, the numerator equals $h$.  This means that when you apply the fraction to the denominator, the $h$ is converted.  If you have any further questions for me, after you follow through with the computation and then think about it, leave me another message.

Answer (score 1):

The limit $3\sqrt[3]4$  is given by the problem and it is easy to calculate. What the problem asks is to use the definition of limit to show that this limit is indeed  $3\sqrt[3]4$. This presents some difficulty.

Let $\epsilon\gt0$ be given. We need to find out $\delta \gt0$ such that $|x|\le \delta\Rightarrow |3\sqrt[3]4-f(x)|\lt\epsilon$.

We’ll prove that $\boxed{\delta =f(-\epsilon)-f(\epsilon)}$ fits.

Let us first notice that $f$ is strictly decreasing in the neighborhood of $0$ (derivative negative).

**Proposition**.- Let us $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+x}-\sqrt[3]2}{x}$ then for $x\gt0$ and near zero we have $0\lt f(-x)-f(x)\lt x$.

**Proof**.- (This is graphically verified with any good calculator, for example Desmos). We have
$$0\lt f(-x)-f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2-x}-\sqrt[3]2}{-x}-\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2+x}-\sqrt[3]2}{x}=\frac{2\sqrt[3]2-\sqrt[3]{2-x}-\sqrt[3]{2+x}}{x} \\0\lt f(-x)-f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{x}\left(2-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac x2}-\sqrt[3]{1+\frac x2}\right)$$

Using Taylor series $$\sqrt[3]{1-t}=1-\frac t3-\frac{t^2}{9}-\frac{5t^3}{81}-\frac{10t^4}{243}+O(t^5)\\\sqrt[3]{1+t}=1+\frac t3-\frac{t^2}{9}+\frac{5t^3}{81}-\frac{10t^4}{243}+O(t^5)$$ It follows
$$ f(-x)-f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{x}\left(\frac29(\frac x2)^2+\frac{10}{243}(\frac x2)^4+O((\frac x2)^6)\right)=\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{x}\left(\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{5x^4}{1944}+O\left(\frac{x^6}{64}\right)\right)$$ $$f(-x)-f(x)= x\left(\sqrt[3]2\left(\frac{1}{18}+\frac{5x^2}{1944}+\frac{1}{x^2}O\left(\frac{x^6}{64}\right)\right)\right)=x\left(\frac{1}{9\sqrt[3]4}+\frac{5x^2}{972\sqrt[3]4}+\frac{\sqrt[3]2}{x^2}O\left(\frac{x^6}{64}\right)\right)\lt x$$
because near zero the factor of $x$ is clearly less than $1$.

Now the rest of the proof is immediate. By construction, being $y_0=3\sqrt[3]4$, if $|x|\lt\delta=f(-\epsilon) -f(\epsilon)$ we have $$|y_0-f(x)|\lt f(-\epsilon) -f(\epsilon)\lt\epsilon$$ See the attached figure for clarity.

[image]